# Proxychains tor + ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, proxy, tor

Heelo, i have a problem with setting proxychains. I config file, when i set

```
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
```

It works well as tor, when i make an ssh tunnel on port 9051 and i use

```
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4 127.0.0.1 9051
```

It also works well with that ssh tunnel, but when i use this settings

```
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
socks4 127.0.0.1 9051
```

with both tor and ssh tunnel opened, it fails. Whats is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your socks proxy servers are not accepting requests to 127.0.0.1 for security reasons. If this is the case then you have to enable an access in the socks server configuration. However, be careful as this may create a security breach in your server.